# How to debug slowdown on a SQL Azure server?

Tags: sql-server, azure

We've had a SQL Azure cloudapp/database in production for a long time and while its performance has been a little volatile, over the last few days it has suddenly dropped drastically. Our application is unresponsive because SQL queries and stored procedures that used to take 5-10 seconds are now taking 90 seconds or more.

What are the things I should check, given that we already do regular index rebuilds/reorgs, clear down large tables when we're finished, etc.

We're still on the "Web" service tier and are planning to move soon to the newer S2 perhaps but we need to tackle this issue.

Comment: you are not alone, we see performance downgrade in last week or so as well.

Comment: Sumit - I would be very interested to hear about that. Which day did it happen?

Comment: I am not sure on day, but my client is complain from last 6-7 days. I am still looking for reason or how to improve it

Comment: Our problem began last tuesday - 7 days ago. We moved DB to a new instance and it seems OK. However, if you're having it too then could be a system issue/downgrade and it may not solve it for long.

Comment: I suspect the same and planning to move db as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) How many active connections does your SQL Azure DB have during slow times?  Things get wierd once you get into 150+ range on a shared plan.
If you have a ton of connections open, that means you're not properly clearing them in your app somewhere.

2) Does your DB have any blocking queries?  DBs with alot of blocking (deadlocking) queries may behave much slower, if you need access to locked resources

3) You should really consider switching to a dedicated SQL Azure plan.  It is very quick to do and no action is required on the app-dev side.  http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/08/azure-update-sql-database-easy-upgrade-to-new-service-tiers-performance-improvements-pitr-for-basic-and-automated-export-for-all-service-tiers/

4) If neither helps, contact support.  This could be an issue on their end

5) Once immediate problems are resolved, consider active monitoring of your SQL Azure db's (link in my profile signature)

Comment: Thanks Igorek. 1) We're not hitting anything like that limit so should be OK. 2) We had one deadlock on Tuesday, one day before performance problems hit. But you're talking about lots of blocking/deadlocking right? 3) We switched to S2 (but some of the user comments on that article you mention are pretty rough on MS... 4) We don't have a support contract. Not my choice unfortunately... 5) I'll have a look!

Comment: Marked as answer since it seems to be an MS issue. We're currently consulting support. Moving to a new DB instance worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.developer.com/services/how-to-identify-performance-bottlenecks-on-azure-sql-database.html

You could also have a device in your network that is slowing down the performance.  You might want to run some network tests to see if the problem is internal or external.  For instance, someone might have changed some firewall or security settings on a rollout and messed it up a bit or a device might be ready to fail.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I've used some of those DMVs previously and (same as today unfortunately) they show similar results i.e. queries in progress, most demanding queries, etc. that they've shown before. It's just that they're ALL taking much longer to run! :(. For example, query plans look similar in our QA/UAT/LIVE instances, but the live one is crazy (5-10 seconds in QA/UA, 4 mins in live - with no load (it's 1AM here!))

Comment: Is it possible to see your connections to the cloud servers and test response times?  One could be acting funky.

Comment: Not sure what to look for there? Our app is very slow so the connection to the Cloud server and DB is affected. If I run stored procedures from my local SQL Managements Studio, to the SQL Azure instance, it's also incredibly slow. The procs aren't transferring large amounts of data over the network - they do a lot of internal processing and then just return about 30 rows.

Comment: As I understand the architecture, you send to a datacenter cloud and the load balancer creates a "sticky" sessions to the TDS protocol tier which then kinda locks you into a set configuration of servers.  So your really never know what you are connected to.  You can look at the overall traffic and see if some of the transactions/ops take longer than others.  Then you can go to the MS folks and say you got a bad server.
 As I don't know anything about your app, I'm just taking shots in the dark.